# JFrame, leaves trail of rectangle

Tags: java, graphics

i'm trying to create a game. And almost everytime I move, it's leaving a trail

Code:

```
package lt.mchackers.gametest.main;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import lt.mchackers.gametest.handlers.InputHandler;

/** 
 * Main class for the game 
 */ 
public class Main extends JFrame 
{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -828018325337767157L;
        boolean isRunning = true; 
        int fps = 30; 
        int windowWidth = 320; 
        int windowHeight = 320;
        int speed;

        BufferedImage backBuffer; 
        Insets insets; 
        InputHandler input; 

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int xa = 0;
        int ya = 0;
        Coordinates coords = new Coordinates(0, 0);

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {       Main game = new Main(); 
                game.run(); 
                System.exit(0); 
        } 

        /** 
         * This method starts the game and runs it in a loop 
         */ 
        public void run() 
        { 
                initialize(); 

                while(isRunning) 
                { 

                        long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

                        update(); 
                        draw(); 

                        //  delay for each frame  -   time it took for one frame 
                        time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time); 

                        if (time > 0) 
                        { 
                                try 
                                { 
                                        Thread.sleep(time); 
                                } 
                                catch(Exception e){} 
                        } 
                } 

                setVisible(false); 
        } 

        /** 
         * This method will set up everything need for the game to run 
         */ 
        void initialize() 
        { 
                setTitle("Game Tutorial"); 
                setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight); 
                setResizable(false); 
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
                setVisible(true); 

                insets = getInsets(); 
                setSize(insets.left + windowWidth + insets.right, 
                                insets.top + windowHeight + insets.bottom); 

                backBuffer = new BufferedImage(windowWidth, windowHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
                input = new InputHandler(this); 
                Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics(); 
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("map"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                String line = null;
                try {
                    BufferedImage gray = ImageIO.read(new File("gray.png"));
                    BufferedImage black = ImageIO.read(new File("black.png"));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        for(String s : line.split(""))
                        {
                            if (s.contains("*"))
                            {
                                bbg.drawImage(gray, xa-32, ya, null);
                            }
                            else if (s.contains("#"))
                            {
                                bbg.drawImage(black, xa-32, ya, null);
                            }
                            if (xa < 320)
                            {
                                xa += 32;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ya += 32;
                                xa = 0;
                            }
                            System.out.println(xa);
                            System.out.println(ya);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        } 

        /** 
         * This method will check for input, move things 
         * around and check for win conditions, etc 
         */ 
        void update() 
        { 
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0))
            {
                speed -= 1;
            }
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1))
            {
                speed += 1;
            }
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) 
            { 
                coords.setCoords(coords.getX() + 32, coords.getY()); 
            } 
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) 
            { 
                coords.setCoords(coords.getX() - 32, coords.getY()); 
            } 
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_UP))
            {
                coords.setCoords(coords.getX(), coords.getY() - 32); 
            }
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
            {
                coords.setCoords(coords.getX(), coords.getY() + 32); 
            }
            //System.out.println(x);
            //System.out.println(y);
            //System.out.println(speed);
            if (coords.getY() < 0)
            {
                coords.setCoords(coords.getX(), 0);
            }
            if (coords.getX() < 0)
            {
                coords.setCoords(0, coords.getY());
            }
            if (coords.getX() > windowWidth - 32)
            {   
                coords.setCoords(windowWidth - 32, coords.getY());
            }
            if (coords.getY() > windowHeight - 32)
            {
                coords.setCoords(coords.getX(), windowHeight - 32); 
            //  y = windowHeight - 32;
            }

        } 

        /** 
         * This method will draw everything 
         */ 
        void draw() 
        {               
                Graphics g = getGraphics(); 
                //this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                //super.paintComponents(g);
                backBuffer.setRGB(x, y, Color.BLACK.getRGB());

                Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics(); 

                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("map"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                String line = null;
                try {
                    BufferedImage gray = ImageIO.read(new File("gray.png"));
                    BufferedImage black = ImageIO.read(new File("black.png"));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        for(String s : line.split(""))
                        {
                            if (s.contains("*") && xa + 32!= coords.getX() && ya - 32 != coords.getY())
                            {
                                bbg.drawImage(gray, xa-32, ya, null);
                            }
                            else if (s.contains("#") && xa + 32 != coords.getX() && ya - 32 != coords.getY())
                            {
                                bbg.drawImage(black, xa-32, ya, null);
                            }
                            if (xa < 320)
                            {
                                xa += 32;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ya += 32;
                                xa = 0;
                            }
                            //System.out.println(xa);
                            //System.out.println(ya);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bbg.setColor(Color.WHITE); 

                xa = 0;
                ya = 0;
                System.out.println(coords.getX());
                bbg.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                bbg.fillRect(coords.getX(),coords.getY(), 32,32);  
                System.out.println(coords.getY());
                //bbg.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
                //bbg.drawOval(x, y, 20, 20); 


                g.drawImage(backBuffer, insets.left, insets.top, this); 
        } 
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Good luck, I hope you find the problem of the code.....

Comment: You probably need to repaint the background other wise the previous position is still visible. Uncommenting the paintcomponent call may do it. Also I would move the reading of files and images out of your draw method. Read them in your init and store them.

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't read the source but do you do a Jframe revalidate and repaint every time

Comment: When I uncomment paintcomponent call, the window's flashing.

Comment: Yeah you are doing waaaay too much work in `draw`.

Comment: Can you tell me, how to make it work ?

Comment: @ZygimantasMagelinskas No. Since I can't run that code. BUT! I can't tell what could be a cause: 1. You are repainting your JFrame in a wrong way. Do not call `Thread.sleep()` on EDT! That could be easy a source of problems. Use swing Timer; 2. You should use JPanel for drawing instead of JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my code from [here](https://github.com/AmanAgnihotri/SnakeGame/blob/master/game/SnakePanel.java), to get a hint as to how to paint stuff in a game loop properly.

Basically what you need to take care of is double buffering to prevent any flickering and also repainting the background so that you don't leave out any trail of rectangles.

You can also check out the [Killer Game Programming in Java](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/) online book, which can help you learn the game programming concepts and their implementation.

The concept of double buffering is simple. Since painting on the screen takes more time than updating the states of the objects in the gameplay, we use two canvas to prevent any flickering issues which arise when objects are painted directly on the screen.

When the object states are updated in the game loop, it is rendered in a background canvas. The background canvas is then copied to the screen which takes less time compared to painting directly on the screen. And while this copying is happening, the object states are updated again and they are rendered on the background canvas again, which is then copied to the screen. Repeat this over and over, and you get the double buffering.
Basically you keep a buffer of screen which is to be painted and your game renders objects in the buffer which is then copied to the screen.

Here's a code which I think might help you understand the concept:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6892533030374996243L;
  public static final int WIDTH = 800;
  public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

  private Thread animator;

  private volatile boolean running = false;
  private volatile boolean isGameOver = false;
  private volatile boolean isUserPaused = false;
  private volatile boolean isWindowPaused = false;

  private Graphics dbg;
  private Image dbImage = null;

  private static final int NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD = 16;
  private static final int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;

  private static final Color backgroundColor = new Color(245, 245, 245);

  private static long fps = 30;
  private static long period = 1000000L * (long) 1000.0 / fps;

  private static volatile boolean isPainted = false;

  public GamePanel()
  {
    setBackground(backgroundColor);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    readyForPause();

    // Add key listeners here...
  }

  public void addNotify()
  {
    super.addNotify();
    startGame();
  }

  void startGame()
  {
    if (animator == null || !running)
    {
      animator = new Thread(this);
      animator.start();
    }
  }

  void stopGame()
  {
    running = false;
  }

  private void readyForPause()
  {
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
      {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Q)
            || (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_END) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_P)
            || ((keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_C) && e.isControlDown()))
        {
          if (!isUserPaused)
            setUserPaused(true);
          else
            setUserPaused(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // This is the game loop. You can copy-paste it even in your own code if you want to.
  public void run()
  {
    long beforeTime, afterTime, timeDiff, sleepTime;
    long overSleepTime = 0L;
    int noDelays = 0;
    long excess = 0L;

    beforeTime = System.nanoTime();

    running = true;

    while (running)
    {
      requestFocus();
      gameUpdate();
      gameRender();
      paintScreen();

      afterTime = System.nanoTime();

      timeDiff = afterTime - beforeTime;
      sleepTime = (period - timeDiff) - overSleepTime;

      if (sleepTime > 0)
      {
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(sleepTime / 1000000L);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }

        overSleepTime = (System.nanoTime() - afterTime - sleepTime);
      }
      else
      {
        excess -= sleepTime;
        overSleepTime = 0L;

        if (++noDelays >= NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD)
        {
          Thread.yield();
          noDelays = 0;
        }
      }

      beforeTime = System.nanoTime();

      int skips = 0;

      while ((excess > period) && (skips < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS))
      {
        excess -= period;
        gameUpdate();
        skips++;
      }

      isPainted = true;
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }

  private void gameUpdate()
  {
    if (!isUserPaused && !isWindowPaused && !isGameOver)
    {
      // Update the state of your game objects here...
    }
  }

  private void gameRender()
  {
    if (dbImage == null)
    {
      dbImage = createImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      if (dbImage == null)
      {
        System.out.println("Image is null.");
        return;
      }
      else
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    }

    dbg.setColor(backgroundColor);
    dbg.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // Render your game objects here....
    // like: xyzObject.draw(dbg);
    // or dbg.drawOval(...);

    if (isGameOver)
      gameOverMessage(dbg);
  }

  private void gameOverMessage(Graphics g)
  {
    // Paint a game over message here..
  }

  private void paintScreen()
  {
    Graphics g;

    try
    {
      g = this.getGraphics();
      if ((g != null) && (dbImage != null))
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
      g.dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Graphics context error : " + e);
    }
  }

  public void setWindowPaused(boolean isPaused)
  {
    isWindowPaused = isPaused;
  }

  public void setUserPaused(boolean isPaused)
  {
    isUserPaused = isPaused;
  }
}
```

Then you can simply add your game panel to your JFrame like following:

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1624735497099558420L;
  private GameFrame gamePanel = new GamePanel();

  public GameFrame()
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Game");

    addWindowListener(new FrameListener());

    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    getContentPane().add(gamePanel);

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public class FrameListener extends WindowAdapter
  {
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent we)
    {
      gamePanel.setWindowPaused(false);
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent we)
    {
      gamePanel.setWindowPaused(true);
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent we)
    {
      gamePanel.setWindowPaused(false);
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent we)
    {
      gamePanel.setWindowPaused(true);
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
      gamePanel.stopGame();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    new GameFrame();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to game programming, could you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Well, my code is all there in the link, you can first see that and let me know if you want to know anything in particular. It's a complete working gameplay, which you can download and play for yourself.

Comment: How to make double buffering ?

Comment: Updated my answer. You can check out the online free book I mentioned to understand double buffering and can also check it out on the internet.

Comment: You can also copy my game loop implementation and use it without getting into the details of how's its implemented, if all you want is to get your game working first. You can learn its nitty gritty later as well.

Comment: Can you show me the code, game from scratch only with painting, and that stuff. Like the start of game coding

Comment: This [link](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ch1/ch1.pdf) will show you how to write game code from scratch with only painting and updating stuff that you want. You can go through it to see how its done. Later you can read the book's further chapters.

Comment: When I copy, there's indent problems. Could you give me good, beautiful code ?

Comment: A hint to resolve your indent issues: You can't just copy-paste code from pdf files if it isn't a very simple pdf file. You can copy individual lines and then get your work done. Or else check out my code from [here](https://github.com/AmanAgnihotri/SnakeGame/blob/master/game/SnakePanel.java). It exactly has what you need. You just need to go through it to get the idea.

Comment: Could you remove the lines, I don't need and post it to pastebin?

Comment: My code is just a framework. You'll have to write your own logic to get the proper behavior out of it for your game. All that I have written is something you can use in its totality. I have used a similar structure for many small games that I have made and they all work fine.

Comment: But there are snake and all those lines.

Comment: Well its a sincere advice: First try to learn the concepts and then approach your game problem. It'll be much easier for you if you give the learning process sometime rather than trying to fit the solution to your expected game solution somehow. Read other people's codes and read game programming in blogs and books. There's a wealth of material out there from which you can learn game programming. Then approach your game.

Comment: It's okey, i'm creating the game. Thank's for the help.

Comment: My apologies that I couldn't help any more in this situation.